# Custom cmdline parsing algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, parsing, data-structures

Im trying on an implementation for custom cmd line having cmds specific for my application.

commands are either single word or multiple words.
say for e.g.

```
-#version      //single word cmd

-#show input pressure  //Multiple word cmds
-#show input temp
```

In order to parse and call the corresponding function pointers i have two tables for the above cmds.

**Table1:** Basic Cmd Table

```
typedef struct CommandStruct{
  char (*f)(uint8 argn, const char **argv);
  char  *fname;
  char  *help;
}CommandStruct;

/*Help information*/
char version_help[] = " Usage:Version \n Command Displays the version information.\n";
char ShowInput_help[] = " \nUsage: \n show input pressure  --Shows input pressure \n \
show input temp -- shows input temperature \n";

 /*Table1 - Basic set of commands*/
CommandStruct basic_command_list[] =
{
   /* function name , cmd name , help information */
   {version    , "version"  , version_help },
   {clear      , "clear"    ,"Clear the screen" },
   {quit       , "quit"     ,"Exit from the prompt" },
   {ShowInput  , "show input", ShowInput_help }, 
   {NULL       ,  NULL      , NULL  }
}; 

  -#show input pressure 
  -#show input temp
```

The above 2 cmds fall under  "show input" in table1.

In the current algorithm, on splitting the input string to tokens ,I check if its a single word or double word. In case of single word i directly call the function.
In case of more than a single word(e.g.Show input temp) ,I take the first 2 tokens (i.e. 'show input' and try to filter and search in the sub table.(here its table2).

```
    /*Table 2 : Sub cmd for the cmds starting with 'show input' */
    CommandStruct show_input_command_list[] =
    {
       /* function name , cmd name , help information */
       {ShowInputPressure  , "pressure", ShowInput_help },
       {ShowInputTemp  , "temp",ShowInput_help},
       {NULL       ,  NULL      , NULL  }
    };
```

This way i continue say for the below cmds I compare and find "show network" once that's matched then i search the table3 which has the network commands.

Some of the other cmds are like

```
show network ipaddress     
show network ipsubnet   
show network abcd<#>

set network ipaddress <#>
set network ipsubnet <#>
set network abcd <#>  <#>
```

So i have to add ShowNetwork to table 1 and create a new table show_network_command_list[] and add the three other cmd .etc .

How to improve this algorithm ? Please suggest me if there is a better solution. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you want to improve? I mean you could always use a lexer / parser to process the input (i.e. [antlr](http://antlr.org/), [flex](http://flex.sourceforge.net/)/[yacc](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) or [ragel](http://www.complang.org/ragel/)), but this could be an overkill if you only have simple commands as the ones you show. Maybe this is a question for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: There can be other algorithms as well which can do better! Thanks for the lexer/parser idea but as you said it will be an overkill. I will be having around 200 cmds like that .

Comment: suspect you should try http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I have updated my question on algorithm perspective. Thanks